# How do I hide my Searchbar when scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem

My SearchController has unintended behaviour of showing up translucent on top of my scrolling content:

[image: Unwanted behaviour]

Ideally, I want it to scroll up with my content and the navigation bar to collapse.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

I'm creating my SearchController in ViewDidLoad like so:

```
    let searchResultsController = SearchViewController(nibName: "SearchViewController", bundle: nil)
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
    searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .sentences

    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Birds"

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self 

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController

    definesPresentationContext = true
```

In ViewWillAppear, I set my NavigationController:

```
    self.navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

I create my Navigation controller in AppDelegate like:
        public func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication)  {
        // Instantiate the initial controller
        let initialViewController = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)

```
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try (If you App runs on iOS 11.0 and more)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
          navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }
}
```

Apple doc:

> If this property is true (the default), the searchController’s search
>   bar will hide as the user scrolls in the top view controller’s scroll
>   view. If false, the search bar will remain visible and pinned
>   underneath the navigation bar.

Comment: What I don't understand is that the default behaviour should be true, so by default the "correct" behaviour should've been active.

Comment: @Stephan can you try by adding navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true while creating search controller?

Comment: I added it, but nope. No change.

Comment: See my updated question for how I create my navigation controller. Might it have something to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't. Do you know what I can look for?

Comment: can you try by adding navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I did, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
```

Comment: Please add some explanations into your answer to help others with similar question in future.

Answer (score 0):

Make your controller confirm to UIScrollViewDelegate and override these methods:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        self.navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This might require some changes as per the aesthetics you are looking for in the app.

Comment: This is definitely not what I'm looking for. The built-in functionality should be sufficient.